# Model class does not update while I change any row data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a model class named: `WebpageRoles`, there is a Boolean field named `isAccessable`. Now I have a query to select value by:

```
var drafts = db.WebpageRoles.Where(d => d.PageId == pageid && d.RoleId == roID).ToList();
```

When I build it, it returns `isAccessable = true`, but when I change it to `false` in database manually, then the query returns the same value (meaning `true`), but the database contains `false`.

When I build it again then it takes new value.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Your query doesn't contain `isAccessable` so i don't understand the question.

Comment: What sort of database are you using? How are you connecting to it? Are you using Entity Framework, for example?

Comment: Are you sure you *saved* the value to the database **and** that the query is being executed again (instead of just re-reading the result to the previous query)?

Comment: Are you edit the values while project is running? There may be data cache. Normally entity framework maintain a cache layer until you save or update data, it will not update the cache. Please try update from the application and try

Comment: When i run application then this function is fired, and return correct value as it is in database. Now i change one value in database and fired again but return me no change value. But when i stop application and run again then it takes new value. Why ?

Comment: Post some sample code

Answer (score 0):

Quite sure you have a **"long running context"**.

That is you have in your startup code : `public static SomeDbContext MyGlobalContext = new SomeDbContext()`

Then, all along your code, you use `MyGlobalContext`. So your context is recycled only at startup and most of the time **you hit the local cache** and not the db. So direct change in the db does not reach your app.